# jsf converter p:calendar date

Tags: jsf, date, calendar, primefaces, converters

Which is the Java class type that a "p:calendar" component is supposed bounded to? (in order to implementing a converter for it).

I thought it was `java.util.Date`, and so I have the following:

```
<p:calendar id="fecha" value="#{catalogoController.criterios.fecha}"
            maxlength="10"
            size="10"
            locale="es"
            pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"
            navigator="true"
            showOn="button"
            showButtonPanel="true" />
```

And the property `catalogoController.criterios.fecha` is a `java.util.Date`.

My custom converter:

```
    @FacesConverter(forClass = java.util.Date.class)
    public class FechaDateConverter implements Converter {
    ...
        public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
            log.info("getAsObject");
            ...
        }
    ...
    }
```

I don't put here the code of the method because it's large. It checks for conditions and throws ConverterException with custom facesmessages, that I get from a custom properties file ("msjsConversion").

But it doesn't work. When I input an incorrect date (for example "01/032011"), my `getAsObject` method isn't triggered (I know because its first log line is never reached). And the default message of conversion is showed as the facesmessage, not the one I get from my bundle "msjsConversion".

I think the reason why it is not triggered is because the Java class to which the `p:calendar` is bound isn't a `java.util.Date` (which is the class for which I declared my converter).

And so, I've checked that if I declare my converter with an ID:

```
@FacesConverter("fechaDateConverter")
public class FechaDateConverter implements Converter {
```

and I put this in the `p:calendar` component:

```
<f:converter converterId="fechaDateConverter" />
```

It works.

So anyone knows which is the Java class of `p:calendar`? So that I could declare my converter for that class, and not use a converterId?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: why do you need a converter fo p:calendar value ? its a simple date http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/calendarBasic.jsf <-- look at the java code...

Comment: My converter is for a simple date (see my question). But it doesn't work if I declare it for any date object '@FacesConverter(forClass = java.util.Date.class)'. It just work if I declare it explicitly for the component with '<f:converter converterId="fechaDateConverter" />
'

Answer (score 2):

> So anyone knows which is the Java class of p:calendar?

It would appear that there isn't one.

Note that this answer applies to primefaces 1.1, I haven't checked later versions may be different.

The conversion from String to Date is done in the getConvertedValue method of org.primefaces.component.calendar.CalendarRenderer

If a converter has been specified (in your p:calendar used on your page) it will be used to convert the date and handle any errors it may encounter.  If no converter is specified then the method attempts to parse the date using the provided pattern (or if no pattern is provided it will fall back to using a default of MM/dd/yyyy).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the attribute **converter** of p:calendar to specify the converter, whether by id (e.g. converter='fechaDateConverter') or by bean name (e.g. converter='#{fechaDateConverter}').

This has the disadvantage that you need to repeat if for every p:calendar...